# How can i get a return value from multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement parallelization in my code, but i can't get results from `multiprocessing.Process`. I have a code that looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    labels = ['neutral', 'bad', 'good']
    procs = []
    for i in labels:
        p = Process(target = process, args = (i, ))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

Function `process` loads NLTK corpus, does some transformation to documents and returns a list. I need to call this function three times with different arguments to process three folders. So i was thinking about running it in parallel. I want to add returned list to a dictionary with a key from `labels`. The result should look like this:

```
result = {'neutral': [returned_list], 'bad': ....
```

I've read about `Queue` and `Pipe` but I couldn't figure out how to use them in my case so I would be glad for any help.

Comment: See [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
import multiprocessing

def action(data):
    return {data:["computed_action"]}

labels = ['neutral', 'bad', 'good']
proc_count = 5
result = multiprocessing.Pool(proc_count).map(action,labels)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[{'neutral': ['computed_action']}, {'bad': ['computed_action']}, {'good': ['computed_action']}]
```

Comment: You could do `proc_count = len(labels)` since it's going to be a small number.

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you. It wasn't working on Spyder IDLE due to some bag, apparently